# Как получить границы / рамки вокруг диапазона в Excel, используя EPPlus в C #

Tags: c#

Код ниже генерирует границы для всех ячеек в пределах диапазона [2, 2, 5, 11], но я хочу, чтобы все было в рамках, как это сделать? .

```
  var FirstTableRange = wsMyWorkSheet.Cells[2, 2, 5, 11];
        FirstTableRange.Style.Border.Top.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thick;
        FirstTableRange.Style.Border.Left.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thick;
        FirstTableRange.Style.Border.Right.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thick;
        FirstTableRange.Style.Border.Bottom.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thick;
```

Comment: 1. Найти это "все". 2. Применить вышеуказанный код.

Comment: вопрос, как это все найти

Comment: Ну это вопрос к вам, что именно вы подразумеваете под "все"?

Comment: все данные, который на данный момент в экселе

Comment: у меня например 22 столбца и н строк, как мне обвести только их?

Comment: Начать с ячейки 1:1 и двигаться вправо/вниз пока не найдем пустую, например. На сколько это применимо — зависит от ваших данных